# Read specific templates and cells from several excel files in Python and concatenate the data in dataframe with for loop

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains different excels with the same layout, the only difference is that some excels contain an extra template with monthly data instead of weekly data. I want to read specific data from the excels that contain the extra template in Python and combine them in one dataframe so that I obtain a time series. One of the specific cells in the excels contains a date. I need this date in a separate column in the dataframe. The problem I have is that it gives me a very strange date (2022-05-25) that isn't even in the excels (contains only data from 2023). Also it reads in too much data, I would expect to have 200 rows, but it seems that the code reads all excels (instead of only the excels with the extra template) as the dataframe contains 999 rows. This is my code:

```
# Get monthly data
# Get the list of excel files in the folder
folder = 'H:\IDH excels'
files = glob.glob(folder + '/*.xlsx')

# Initialize an empty list to store the dataframes
dfs1 = []

# Loop over the files
for file in files:
    # Open the excel file and get the sheet names
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    # Check if the sheet "Template B - Monthly" exists
    if "Template B - Monthly" in sheets:
        # Read the excel file and extract the data from the sheet
        df1 = pd.read_excel(file, "Template B - Monthly", usecols='A:C,AL:AS,AW', skiprows=12, skipfooter=59)
        # Get the value of cell B5 and assign it to a new column
        date1 = pd.to_datetime(pd.read_excel(file,"Template B - Monthly").iloc[3, 1],format='%d.%m.%Y')
        df1['Date'] = date1
        # Append the dataframe to the list
        dfs1.append(df1)
    else:
        # Skip the file and continue with the next one
        continue

# Concatenate the dataframes into one dataframe
final_df1 = pd.concat(dfs1, ignore_index=True)
```

Hopefully one of you could help me out. Thanks in advance!